# Setting up the configuration of sqlite3 database in Python SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD

Tags: python, database, multithreading, sqlite

As per the sqlite3 documentation http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#threadsafe:

> "When SQLite has been compiled with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 or
>   SQLITE_THREADSAFE=2 then the threading mode can be altered at run-time
>   using the sqlite3_config() interface together with one of these verbs:
>
> ```
> SQLITE_CONFIG_SINGLETHREAD
> SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD
> SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED "
> ```

Can you please help me with the proper Python syntax for configuring a database with SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1 and SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD

Thank you for reading, and apologies for filling up stackoverflow with such a basic problem.

BTW, if it matters at all, what I am doing is, I have multiple threads running, and in each I have a several calls to different database connections. The python script worked well when running on the windows machine I originally wrote it on, but now that I have migrated it to an Ubuntu machine I get "ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.." I tried connecting with check_same_thread = False but then I get an error that the database is locked. This is why I need to see if the configs above may help solve my problem, I just have trouble with their syntax.

Comment: Are you sharing a connection or cursor object between threads?

Comment: Hi Martijn, no I do not.

Comment: The exception suggests that you *are* doing this; give each thread its own connection to the same database and everything will work just fine.

Comment: I will check again! Still, for the sake of education, how would I syntax the above configs?

Comment: I don't know; I don't think the `sqlite3_config` C call is exposed to Python.

Comment: Ok, thanks for spending time with me on this one. It appears you were right after all, I did share a connection between threads. I am really puzzled though, why the same program program ran perfectly well on windows, but not on Ubuntu...

Comment: The Windows threading implementation differs, and perhaps the specific circumstances did not occur there due to subtle scheduling differences?