# Unique Constraint in sqlite does not always raise IntegrityError

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using [Python's sqlite3 wrappers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html):

I have a table that I create using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patientsname (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    original,
    cleaned,
    study INTEGER,
    UNIQUE(original, study),
    FOREIGN KEY(study) REFERENCES studyinstanceuid(id)
)
```

If I try to insert multiple time for the same `(original, id)` I usually get:

```
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: patientsname.original, patientsname.study
```

every once in a while I get (I have seen on OSX):

```
OperationalError: UNIQUE constraint failed: patientsname.original, patientsname.study
```

and seen on Linux:

```
DatabaseError: UNIQUE constraint failed: patientsname.original, patientsname.study
```

What is the correct way to catch the unique constraint violation?

UPDATE. Versions that see `OperationalError`:

```
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.2'
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

and:

```
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.8.7.4'
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

Comment: What is the SQLite version in each case? Look at `sqlite3.sqlite_version`. The library version would also be helpful, see `sqlite3.version`. It *could* be that the C library (not the Python extension) is being inconsistent about how it is communicating integrity errors; is it the exact same SQL query that throws the different exceptions?

Comment: Is that version the same *across all platforms*? What code did you use to reproduce the exceptions?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cancan101/17241bf59841ed96fb8f

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403615/setting-up-the-configuration-of-sqlite3-database-in-python-sqlite-config-multith since I am sharing the connection across threads.

Comment: I get `OperationalError: SQL logic error or missing database` on Python 2.7.9 on OS X with that. That or a segmentation fault.

Comment: Give it a shot on Linux as well if you can see what you get. That being said what is the solution to this? It seems that seg-faults are not ideal. Is it a bug in the wrapper or is there something that I am doing wrong in order to use the connection across threads?

Comment: I got the same exception on Linux (and both on Mac and Linux the interpreter is also entirely locked up, keyboard interrupts no longer work). Surely you can come up with a script that doesn't to need to share the connection between threads?

Comment: I could use thread locals in python to create a new connection per thread but this solution won't work for in memory database.